# wget, curl, html parsers fail to get correct html

Tags: html, parsing, curl, html-parsing, wget

I'm trying to parse this link

```
http://www.sears.com/search=play%20station?pageNum=1&viewType=list
```

If I open the website in my browser it works perfectly. However, none of parsers seems to work (trying jsoup). Also, I tried doing a curl and wget to the url and the output is not correct either.

I tried to check if the website actually redirects (301, 302) but apparently it does not.

Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I thought it might be user agent, but that does not seem to be it.

Comment: Some websites seem to have some type of blocker for unidentified requests. Facebook has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing a JavaScript redirect to http://www.sears.com/search=play%20station?storeId=10153&catalogId=12605&vName=Movies+Music+%26+Gaming&viewItems=25&viewType=list&autoRedirect=true&redirectType=CAT_REC_PRED&intShip=3&intlDelivery=3 which you can grab with cURL just fine :)

Comment: It doesn't work. I noticed the javascript redirection but I don't think it matters much.

If you curl -L that url you'll get something but it's wrong data. Just check the header:

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

This is obviously wrong.

Comment: When I cURL the URL I posted it works fine.  I only get that obviously wrong header on your original URL.

Comment: Maybe it's my connection or DNS. I'm going to double check.

Comment: @singpolyma is correct.  The initial response to the URL you show is a 200 that loads a page containing _only_ a script, which issues a new request, which returns the actual content.  I tried it under Firefox/Fiddler and Firebug, as well as curl and got the same results.  If you get different results there's something wrong with your setup.